# Gstreamer aesenc/aesdec not working when write to/read from file

Tags: aes, gstreamer

I need to encrypt a video and then later play it back with gstreamer.

Encrypting and decrypting in one command works:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test-plain.mp4 ! aesenc key=1f9423681beb9a79215820f6bda73d0f iv=e9aa8e834d8d70b7e0d254ff670dd718 ! aesdec key=1f9423681beb9a79215820f6bda73d0f iv=e9aa8e834d8d70b7e0d254ff670dd718 ! queue ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

However, writing the encrypted video to a file and then trying to play it does not work:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test-plain.mp4 ! aesenc key=1f9423681beb9a79215820f6bda73d0f iv=e9aa8e834d8d70b7e0d254ff670dd718 ! filesink location=test.enc

gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test.enc ! aesdec key=1f9423681beb9a79215820f6bda73d0f iv=e9aa8e834d8d70b7e0d254ff670dd718 ! queue ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

The playback error is:

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAesDec:aesdec0: Corrupt cipher text.
Additional debug info:
../ext/aes/gstaesdec.c(494): gst_aes_dec_transform (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAesDec:aesdec0:
Illegal PKCS7 padding value 183
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3127): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0:
streaming stopped, reason error (-5)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind: Stream doesn't contain enough data.
Additional debug info:
../plugins/elements/gsttypefindelement.c(1014): gst_type_find_element_chain_do_typefinding (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind:
Can't typefind stream
```

I added what seems to be a more appropriate per-buffer-padding=false argument to the aesenc and aesdec, and get a different type of error:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=test-aes-pbp-off.enc ! aesdec key=1f9423681beb9a79215820f6bda73d0f iv=e9aa8e834d8d70b7e0d254ff670dd718 per-buffer-padding=false ! decodebin ! autovideosink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src: caps = video/mpeg, systemstream=(boolean)false, mpegversion=(int)4, parsed=(boolean)false
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src: caps = NULL
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMpeg4VParse:mpeg4vparse0: No valid frames found before end of stream
Additional debug info:
../libs/gst/base/gstbaseparse.c(3673): gst_base_parse_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMpeg4VParse:mpeg4vparse0
```

If I use a filesink instead of trying to play the video it does create a playable video file.

Comment: I would re-run your first pipeline with the `-v` flag, maybe `decodebin` is expecting some sort of caps filter to know the type of data the original video file contains. I also don't know if the file can be decrypted in chucks either. On your third pipeline instead of trying to play back the file, just use a `filesink` instead and try to playback the decrypted file to verify data is intact.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the issue with more info.